# Modification of field in form

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I have form:

```
class myContact(forms.Form):
  subject = forms.CharField()
  email = forms.EmailField(required=True)`
```

using `myContact().as_table()` I can generate such html code:

```
<tr>
  <th><label for="id_subject">Subject:</label></th>
  <td><input id="id_subject" name="subject" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th><label for="id_email">Email:</label></th>
  <td><input id="id_email" name="email" type="email" /></td>
</tr>
```

how should I change form to get something like this:

```
<tr>
  <th><label for="id_subject">Subject:</label></th>
  <td><input id="id_subject" name="subject" type="text" /></td>
  <td>new_field</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <th><label for="id_email">Email:</label></th>
  <td><input id="id_email" name="email" type="email" /></td>
  <td>new_field</td>
</tr>
```

added new `td` at the end of field

Comment: What that last td is for? Honestly, I can't see a reason to do that.

Comment: I need to build table like this:

description | field(input, textarea or select) | [here something]

in [here something] can be eq. edit/delete button for this field

Comment: you can render this as `as_ul`, and use CSS to display the grid however you want right?

Comment: about what you talking? :O

Answer (score 0):

In this case you want to render fields manually. Each field you can render like this:

```
{{ form.name_of_field }}
```

Read more at docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually

I'm not sure if this is right, but now your code should look something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ form.subject}}</td>
        <td>new_field</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ form.email}}</td>
        <td>new_field</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I think that this is good direction but... with code

`template = get_template('contact.html')
    output = template.render(Context({'form': myContact()}))
    return HttpResponse(output)`

and code.html: `<table>
    <tr>
        {{ form.subject}}
        <td>new_field</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        {{ form.email}}
        <td>new_field</td>
    </tr>
</table>`

output is:

`
<table>
    <tr>
        <input id="id_subject" name="subject" type="text" />
        <td>new_field</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <input id="id_email" name="email" type="email" />
        <td>new_field</td>`

Comment: so what now should I do to get <td></td> over inputs? I must do it manualny?

Comment: Yes, you should. By the way, the same as <th> above the inputs.

Comment: What? Something didn't work out? By the way, if my answer was any helpful vote it up :)